# Sitecore install name not unique error

Tags: sitecore

I was trying to set up a Sitecore dev instance and I accidentally installed to the wrong path.  It seemed like the easiest way to fix this was to delete the IIS instance, and remove the Sitecore DB's.

Unfortunately, I am now getting an error when I try to uninstall ("An error caused the Sitecore Installation Wizard to end prematurely"), and a "not a unique name" error when I try to install a new instance. What do I need to do to allow me to use the same instance name again?

Comment: I almost never use the installer to create a new instance, but prefer to use the .zip file and do manual install. Which is a bit more work but gives me full control on my instance and no unwanted registry keys etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, @OptimizedQuery got me most of the way, until the Windows uninstaller stopped working. I then went into the registry and found the relevant entries here `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sitecore CMS]`.

So, here is a list of steps.

1. Try the Sitecore installer and choose to remove the offending instance.
2. If that fails, manually remove it from IIS and delete the databases before using the uninstaller in the `Programs and Features` application.
3. If that fails, use `regedit` and delete the relevant children of `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sitecore CMS]`. Be sure to delete only the one with the matching `InstanceName` key.

Comment: On my windows 7 64 bit machine it was in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Sitecore CMS]

Comment: And even after removing these, I still couldn't cleanly uninstall my previous duplicate instances.  Finally tried a Microsoft FixIt Program Install and Uninstall Utitlity here: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall, then deleted the databases, IIS bindings, inetpub folder, and host files entries, and after all that, I was able to reinstall cleanly and without errors.

Answer (score 6):

Try uninstalling that Sitecore instance via the Windows Programs and Features dialog within the Control Panel.

Comment: It works... and I have lost a little bit more of my trust in humanity. This is a bug which is counter-intuitive, unnecessary, and almost immoral.

Comment: How is a method of uninstall sitecore immoral? @cwallenpoole

Answer (score 2):

@cwallenpoole the path is wrong. Sitecore is installed in a different location like the followings:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Sitecore CMS]

So the steps look like the following to uninstall:

1. try to uninstall by using sitecore installer and choose the instance to uninstall
2. try to remove form Control Panel > Programs and Features and then choose the instance to remove or uninstall
3. if the above steps are failed, then go to the regristry and choose the path [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Sitecore CMS] and then choose the instance to uninstall

Hope, it will work for most cases. if you find any more steps, please add those :)  happy uninstalling!